# Avision Scanner not found with WIA

Tags: c#, .net, wia, image-scanner

I am trying to create an app with a button for scanning.

I followed this [post](http://miljenkobarbir.com/using-a-scanner-without-dialogs-in-net) but "WIAScanner.GetDevices()" returns 0 devices.

I am using windows 7 64bit, and i have an 'Avision Sheetfed Scanner AV186U' connected with usb.

Is there anything else i need to do/install?

(btw - the scanner is working well with the build in programs)

Thanks

Yuval

Comment: Is the built-in program x86 or x64? And how about your own program? This link might be helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539324(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hi Rachel, 
i try to compile for both x64 and x86 but no luck,   i do not know about the build in programs.
the problem is that the WIA.DeviceManager returns no resaults

Comment: When you use the built in program for scanning, does it use the WIA driver? You may also have a try with this online TWAIN scanning demo and see how it works with your scanner: http://www.dynamsoft.com/demo/DWT/online_demo_scan.aspx